# History and significance of term "lid"

Tags: cw, jargon

What is the history on the term “lid” when referring to a telegrapher’s capability? How did it originate and what is the significance if any of each letter?

Comment: I have seen this question asked many times over the years on other forums.  And, there have always been many answers.  None of the answers that I can recall were definitive as the historical origination.  In my opinion, no one knows.  However, in my early ham experience 50+ years ago, I never recall this term being used.  I submit it was invented after the late 1960s.  However, maybe this forum is different and someone knows the correct answer for certain.

Comment: Try this one https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31818/how-did-the-word-lid-come-to-mean-poor-operator-in-the-context-of-telegraph full of historical excerpts

Answer (score 1):

KD8NXH, GE OM,

As you say, there are many answers. I was licensed about 44 years ago which might make me a "novice" HIHI. In the absence of a definitive definition, I usually resort to "which one appeals to me the most, personally". As an avid collector in my youth of tin containers for storing small parts, I quite like this one from Rod (SK RIP) and Jeff Dinkins AC6V [ORIGIN OF HAM SPEAK -  FACT, LEGENDS AND MYTHS???](http://www.ac6v.com/73.htm) They write, "Certainly, the term LID came from land-line telegrapher slang. (LID was a reference to use of a tobacco can lid on the sounder to aid a poor operator in copying Morse.) This one may be true. It wouldn't be the first time that a group adopted a term originally meant as an insult to serve as a slang term for themselves." :-)

Incidentally, I still have many of my old 1970's tobacco tins somewhere. According to [this Etsy seller, my tobacco tins could be worth about £5 (US $9.25)](https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/183597634/lloyds-old-holborn-blended-virginia) - I should start looking for them!

73'S ES GD DX DE MART G8EAD